# Select folder and write in a textbox the output powershell

Tags: user-interface, powershell, directory

I have created an application in powershell, and now i need to add the GUI to the app.

In this application I need to give the user the opportunity to **select** or **write** the path of a folder in a textbok. I have written this piece of code but i haven't achieved to get the output of calling the `get-FolderLocation` function in the texbox that i create.

[image]

Any ideas about how to achieve this?

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “System.Windows.Forms”)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “Microsoft.VisualBasic”)

#####Define the form size & placement

$form = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Form”;
$form.Width = 500;
$form.Height = 150;
$form.Text = $title;
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;

##############Define text label1
$textLabel1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel1.Left = 25;
$textLabel1.Top = 15;
$textLabel1.Text = "select the folder";

############Define text box1 for input
$textBox1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox1.Left = 150;
$textBox1.Top = 10;
$textBox1.width = 200;
$textBox1.Text = "selected folder"  

#############define select button
$button = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Button”;
$button.Left = 360;
$button.Top = 85;
$button.Width = 100;
$button.Text = “Browse”;

############# the output of calling the get-Folder Location function must be shown in the textbox1

$button.Add_Click({get-Folderlocation}) ;

#############Add controls to all the above objects defined
$form.Controls.Add($button);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel1);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox1);

$form.ShowDialog();
$textBox1.Text



$selectedDirectory


function get-Folderlocation([string]$Message, [string]$InitialDirectory, [switch]$NoNewFolderButton)
{
    $browseForFolderOptions = 0
    if ($NoNewFolderButton) { $browseForFolderOptions += 512 }

    $app = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $folder = $app.BrowseForFolder(0, $Message, $browseForFolderOptions, $InitialDirectory)
    if ($folder) { $selectedDirectory = $folder.Self.Path } else { $selectedDirectory = '' }
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($app) > $null
    return $selectedDirectory
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply assign the output from `get-FolderLocation` to `$textBox1.Text`.

Since the `$textBox1` variable is not in the same scope as the `add_Click()` scriptblock, PowerShell 3.0 and 4.0 will have issues resolving it. Use `Get-Variable -Scope 1` to work around this:

```
$button.Add_Click({(Get-Variable -Name textBox1 -Scope 1).Value.Text = Get-Folderlocation})
```

Comment: thaaanks it works perfect in new versions of powershell, but i have tried in powershell 2.0 and does work. The error that im getting in powershell 2,0 it that the  Get-Folderlocation ist recognised as a cmdlet

Comment: @kimopryvt move the function definition up *before* `$form.ShowDialog()` :)

Comment: I have moved function Up and works but when I select the folder I get this error. "The scope number '1' exceeds the number of active scopes."

Comment: Remove it and assign directly to $textBox1.Text then

Comment: $button.Add_Click({(Get-Variable -Name textBox1).Value.Text = Get-Folderlocation})